# Video not loading when using an iframe in Node-webkit

Tags: html, iframe, node-webkit

I'm using Node-webkit for a portfolio of a client. Since the client wants to add stuff later in decide to use an iframe so that another separate html could be loaded into the page.

My problem is that one of the products contains a video. When I test the portfolio in Chrome it works just fine. The video normaly loads in the iframe but when I test out the portfolio in Node-webkit the video doesn't load.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Node-webkit doesn't support .mp4 files since you need a license to use that format. There is a work arround where you can copy and paste a .dll file from chrome to nodewebkit but it didn't work for me. For those who wanna try here is a [link](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki/Support-mp3-and-h264-in-video-and-audio-tag)
I myself will just convert the video's to ogg or webm format since that is supported by node-webkit.